# recommended chunk size for sending in C?

Tags: c, networking

I have a server which needs to transfer a large amount of data (~1-2 gigs) per request. What is the recommended amount of data that each call to send should have? Does it matter?

Comment: The answer depends on several factors: the filesystem block size and the PMTU between the client and server.  If you subtract the packet headers from the PMTU, then use the largest multiple of the filesystem block size that is less than or equal to that value.

Comment: make experiments and chose a size that works better

Comment: I'd probably go with something equal to or smaller than the MTU size, maybe even 80% of that, to avoid in-network fragmentation.  Are you going over a LAN only?  Or are you trying to go across the internet?

Comment: @jedwards this is meant to go over the internet

Comment: @jedwards How? How can he discover the path MTU, and how can he dictate the packet size to TCP? And what exactly do you think the TCP/IP stack is for if it doesn't organize your data into MTU-sized packets for you?

Comment: @EJP This approach isn't a great idea when going over the internet, as the PMTU can change -- I was hoping it was for a LAN or controlled environment where the PMTU would be relatively stable.  In any case, you can set the Don't Fragment bit and play around with payload sizes to discover the PMTU.  If you specify a length less than the TCP buffer in the `send` command, it will send exactly the specified number of payload bytes.  As for the last question, it's really beyond the scope of a comment response, but many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP/IP stack takes care of not sending packets larger than the PATH MTU, and you would have to work rather hard to make it send packets *smaller* than the MTU, in ways that wouldn't help throughput: and there is no way of dsicovering what the path PTU actually is for any given connection. So leave all consideration of the path MTU out of it.

You can and should make every `send()` as big as possible.

Comment: I could make `send()` 1-2 gb large, but that is also unreasonable because of the memory bandwidth. So where is the middle point?

Comment: @chacham15 It is unreasonable because of the memory *usage*, not the 'memory bandwidth'. So pick a buffer that suits your memory budget. I usually use 8192 but there's not reason not to use a megabyte, if can spare it.

Answer (score 1):

Your packet size is constraint by the Maximum Transfer Unit (MTU) of the protocol. If you send a packet bigger than the MTU then you get packet fragmentation.

You can do some math: http://www.speedguide.net/articles/mtu-what-difference-does-it-make--111
More References: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

But ultimately my suggestion is that if you aim for good enough and just let the os network layer do its work, unless you are programming raw sockets or passing some funky options, is pretty common that the os will have a network buffer and will try to do its best.

Considering this last option then the socket.send() is nothing else than a memory transfer from your user process memory to the kernel's private memory. The rule of thumb is to not exceed the virtual memory page size http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory) that is usually 4KB.

Comment: Yea, I thought that there might be a buffer which handled this but I wasnt sure. Still, what is a 'reasonable' amount to send then?

Comment: You *can't* 'send a packet bigger than the MTU [and] get packet fragmentation'. The TCP/IP stack won't do that. A socket send buffer should be far larger than 4k, ideally 64k-1.